# Best way to show password in case of Unshowing password field?

Tags: forms, input-fields, password

I'm developing a Desktop JavaFX application using [ControlFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/). I have a problem that CustomPasswordField can not show password text instead of points (PasswordField limitation ), it needs some custom implementation. I'm looking for the way to show the password.

This is the password field form :
[image]

What should I use to show password text (Label, PopOver) and where is the best place to put it ?

Comment: All the show-password options I've seen do it "in field", so from a UX perspective, I'd say the correct answer is "_show it in the field_". _How_ you do this is simply an "implementation problem"... :-) (Which might better be asked on the main SO site).

Answer (score 2):

As you currently phrased the question, it's an implementation issue. There are ways to improve the design though. For one you may want to have the show-password icon in the field itself, because it applies to that field.

You can also show the error message below the input field. The password requirements can be pushed down by this message. Then you have the two messages next to each other which helps the user identify the problem faster. If password length is a thing, you should show that too in your requirements. Hidden requirements are quite annoying since you can't tell until you have the field out of focus or press submit. Especially if you did outline other requirements.

[image]

Comment: But this field does not accept to show characters instead of points .

Comment: If you can't make it accept showing the password, or if you end up with counter intuitive solutions, it's probably better to just not have the feature.